# Spring form:input for number

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags, spring-form

I am using Spring's form:input as below :

```
<form:input type="number" .....>
```

in my jsp but when I check the html that is rendered on the browser it shows like :

```
type="number" type="text"
```

i.e., two `type` attributes are generated in the html.

On the other hand, if I check using *inspect element option* in the browser, it shows correct - only `type="number"` as expected.
**Edit**- My Question: Why am I getting two type attributes in generated html (`type="number" type="text"`) ? How to get it resolved?

Comment: so what is your question ?  doesnt work as expected ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring `form:input` tag doesnt have any attribute named `type` and the `type=number` used in your code belongs to [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) input tag

Also have a look at [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Spring form tld lists the valid attributes of `form:input` element [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input)

Comment: so does it mean that if I need to remove the extra "type" from my html then I have to use the html's <input type="" ...> instead of spring's form tag ?

Comment: yes you should , if you are going to use the UN-defined attribute to the tag it becomes meaningless isnt ?

Comment: I'm using spring form and I want to allow only numerics in the `form:input`, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML 5** 
with `<!DOCTYPE html>` has [native solution](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#number-state-typenumber):

`<input type="number">`

**Beware that it [does not behave in standard way in some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number).**

Try [input type="number"](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number) to see the HTML5 version in action.

See also https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill for transparent support in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but i found a solution that works just fine for me.

The `spring:input` form tag doesnt support the `type` attribute and there is no such thing as `spring:number`.
But you can use jquery to add the `type="number"` attribute to the parsed html.

I used:

```
$(".selector").attr({
    "type" : "number",
});
```